# How to return to execution of cmd command after ftp command "bye"?

Tags: windows, ftp, cmd

I have .bat file. It looks like next

```
....many commands1
ftp -i -s:copy.txt
...many commands2
```

copy.txt contains next commands

```
open ...
login
password
get file
bye
```

When I execute my .bat file it works next

```
many commands1
ftp commands
```

But many commands2 remain don't excuted.

Comment: Should work, but "many commands2" will be executed of course after ftp finished. Are you sure it reaches the "bye"?

Comment: yes :)
I see:
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.

Comment: This should work.  If you leave echoing on (i.e. don't use "echo off") what do you see after the "ftp> bye 221..."?

Comment: That means your FTP script gets executed just fine, so you need to look at the next line in the script and find out why that one won't run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **sounds** like one of your `command2` commands may be calling (launching) a batch file without using the `CALL` command. (At the bottom are two Flowcharts explaining the consequences of using and not using `CALL`.) See **The consequences of using and not using `CALL`.

---

If my initial hunch is incorrect, you need to start taking steps to debug your batch files.

Comment-out any `@ECHO OFF` statements and put some `PAUSE` and maybe even `ECHO` statements in your batch files. This will help you locate your errors. Also, remember that you'll need to use the `CALL` command if you expect for your code to execute a batch file, then continue executing the `CALL`ing batch file after it finishes executing the `CALL`ed batch file. Also, realize that if you `CALL` any batch file containing an `ECHO OFF` statement, that `ECHO OFF` continues to be enforced even after control returns to the `CALL`ing file. For instance:

```
:: For debugging porpuses we leave `ECHO` in it's default `ON` state
REM @echo off

:: Execute your leading commands:
commands1

:: If you prefer, because you know that your problem comes after this point;
:: You can, if you want, leave the leading `ECHO OFF` command alone, and
:: instead, put an `ECHO ON` statement here:
echo on

ftp -i -s:copy.txt
ECHO Back from FTPing...
pause

:: Calling command2.1.exe
command2.1.exe
echo Back from command2.1.exe
pause

:: Calling command2.2.bat
CALL command2.2.bat

:: Since Command2.2.bat contains an ECHO OFF statement
:: we'll turn `ECHO` back on again for debugging purposes.
ECHO ON

echo Back from command2.2.bat
pause
```

---

### The consequences of using and not using `CALL`.

Assuming these two batch files:

`RUN.BAT`

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting: RUN.BAT
(Misc commands)

:: 'Calling' SECOND.BAT without useing `CALL`
SECOND.BATCH

:: Back from SECOND.BAT
ECHO Back from second.bat
```

`SECOND.BAT`

```
@echo off
ECHO Running: SECOND.BAT
```

The flow of execution without a `CALL` statement, will move like this:

```
C:\> RUN.BAT<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
      |
     \|/
      v
@echo off
echo Running
(misc commands)
      |
     \|/
      v
SECOND.BAT   ---->   @echo off
                     echo Running Seond.bat
                     (misc commands)
                      |
                     \|/
                      v
                     END
```

But if you change to `SECOND.BAT` line in the `RUN.BAT` file to `CALL SECOND.BAT`, the flow of execution will go like this:

```
C:\> RUN.BAT<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
      |
     \|/
      v
@echo off
echo Running
(misc commands)
      |
     \|/
      v
SECOND.BAT   ---->   @echo off
                     echo Running Seond.bat
                     (misc commands)
                            |
                           \|/
                            v
:: Back from SECOND.BAT  <--+
      |
     \|/
      v
ECHO Back from second.bat
      |
     \|/
      v
     END
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - It's common practice here. Get used to it. I notice that your edit of my answer concerning the same issue was rejected. That was a hint.

Comment: @JamesK Bad practice is bad, regardless of as how common it may be perceived. I maintain: do not abuse labels as comments.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Then it is good I don't write code for you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Note that not only was your attempted edit been rejected by the community, but that your -1 comment has also been removed as "Off-Topic".